# Normal modes of oscillation: how to find them?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

Are normal modes the eigenvectors of the matrix $(\omega ^2 T- V)$ where $T$ is the matrix of kinetic energy and $V$ is the matrix of potential energy?

Is it the only way to express them?

How can I express them using the coordinates that I have choosen at the beginning of the exercise?

Comment: $V$ will be the matrix of the derivatives of the potential energy.

Comment: @AlecS V is the matrix of coefficients of the coordinates and near the position of equilibrium it can be approximated to hessian matrix of the potential energy... are we saying the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, we are saying the same thing.

Comment: @user1104 Could you help me?

Comment: Could you give me a little more context?

Comment: @user1104 Sure! In the exercises that I'm doing I have to find the Lagrangian of the system, to study points of equilibrium and to write normal modes using initial coordinates. If you need other informations, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Have you tried to compute the two matrices? Just solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors like a typical linear algebra problem.

Comment: @user1104 Yes. I know how to do that. But my question is how can I find normal modes? are they the eigenvectors of the matrix $\omega^2 T -V$? and how can I express them using the coordinates that I have choosen at the beginning of the exercise? (happy new year!)

Comment: You should just post the problem itself. I can't be more clear without an example.

Comment: Posterior Related : [Eigenvalue equation for kinetic and potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266889/eigenvalue-equation-for-kinetic-and-potential-energy).

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at this example

[image]

$$T=\frac{m_1}{2}\dot x_1^2+\frac{m_2}{2}\dot x_2^2\\
V=-\frac{k_1}{2}\,x_1^2-\frac{k_2}{2}\,x_2^2-\frac{k_3}{2}\,(x_1-x_2)^2$$

from here you obtain

$$M_{ij}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot x_i}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot x_j}\right)\\
K_{ij}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial  x_j}\right)$$

hence

$$\underbrace{\left[M\,\omega^2 -K\right]}_{A}\,\vec v=0$$

the solution

from the matrix A you obtain the eigenvalues $\omega_1~,\omega_2~$ and for each eigenvalue  the eigen vector  $~\Rightarrow\quad \vec v_1~,\vec v_2~$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1(t) \\
  x_2(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{c_1\,\vec v_1\,\cos(\omega_1\,t\,+\phi_1)}_{\vec\eta_1}+\underbrace{c_2\,\vec v_2\,\cos(\omega_2\,t\,+\phi_2)}_{\vec\eta_2}$$

where $c_i~,\phi_i~$ are the initial conditions and $~\vec\eta_i~$ are the normal modes

---

$$ M=\begin{bmatrix}
   m_1 & 0 \\
   0 & m_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad,
K= -\begin{bmatrix}
   k_1+k_3 & -k_3 \\
   -k_3 & k_2+k_3 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$