# How to calculate the potential energy of coupled oscillators?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring, oscillators

[image]

The equations of motion that describe the above situation is given by:

$$ m \ddot{x_1} = -2kx_1 + kx_2 $$

$$ m \ddot{x_2} = -2kx_2 + kx_1 $$

Now I want to work out the potential energy of this system. How would I use the equation:

$$ V(x) = - \int F(x) \hspace{.1cm} dx$$

to calculate the potential energy?

My attempt is to first calculate the integral for each coupled equation wrt each position:

$$ - \int (- 2kx_1 + + kx_2) \hspace{.1cm} dx_1= kx^{2}_1 - k x_1 x_2 + c$$
$$ - \int (- 2kx_2 + + kx_1) \hspace{.1cm} dx_2= kx^{2}_2 - k x_2 x_1 + d.$$

Now adding them together to get the total potential energy gives:

$$ V(x_1, x_2) = kx^{2}_1 + kx^{2}_2 + - 2  k x_1 x_2 + f.$$

The actual solution is given by:

$$ V(x_1, x_2) = kx^{2}_1 + kx^{2}_2 + -  k x_1 x_2$$

Now I have inkling as to why my answer is wrong. When adding the potentials together to calculate the total potential I have double added the potential associated with the middle spring. However, mathematically how do I fix this issue to get the correct solution?

Comment: Remember that a spring has energy $\frac 12 k(x_{1}-x_0 -a)^2$ where $a$ is it's natural length.

Comment: Related : [Eigenvalue equation for kinetic and potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266889/eigenvalue-equation-for-kinetic-and-potential-energy/267096#267096).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mikestone suggested in the comments, the easiest way to solve this problem is by summing the potential energies of all the springs.

However, I would like to  comment on the approach described in the question: the equations of motion can be written as
$$
m\ddot{x}_1 = -\frac{\partial V(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1} = -2kx_1 + kx_2,\\
m\ddot{x}_2 = -\frac{\partial V(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_2} = -2kx_2 + kx_1,
$$
where $V(x_1, x_2)$ is the potential energy of the two oscillators. We thus have two partial differential equations (pde) for this potential energy. Integrating the first one in respect to $x_1$ we obtain:
$$
V(x_1, x_2) = kx_1^2 - kx_2x_1 + C(x_2),
$$
i.e. we obtain $V(x_1, x_2)$ up to an unknown constant, $C(x_2)$, which may be dependent on $x_2$ (since the differential equation is in respect to $x_1$). Substituting this into the second equation we obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial V(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_2} =
-kx_1 +\frac{dC(x_2)}{dx_2} 
= 2kx_2 - kx_1,
$$
that is
$$
\frac{dC(x_2)}{dx_2} = 2kx_2 \Rightarrow C(x_2) = kx_2^2
$$
(up to a constant independent on either $x_1$ or $x_2$),
and we obtain
$$
V(x_1, x_2) = kx_1^2 + kx_2^2 -kx_1x_2.
$$

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Question Can be Solved without Integration. Potential Energy is stored in the springs only.

[image]

Let The Rightmost spring is stretched by amount $ x_2$, And the Leftmost spring is stretched by amount $ x_1$
then the Middle spring will be stretched by amount $(x_2 - x_1)$.($As\ shown\ in  
 \ figure $)
$$(2a +x_2)-(a+ x_1)= a+ x_2 - x_1 \qquad (Proof)$$

where a is the length of spring.

The Potential energy of the spring is given by $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}kx^{2} $

Potential energy of leftmost spring is $V(x_1) = \frac{1}{2}kx^{2}_1  \qquad ...(1)  $

Potential energy of rightmost spring is $V(x_2) = \frac{1}{2}kx^{2}_2   \qquad ...(2)$

Potential energy of Middle spring is $V(x_3) = \frac{1}{2}k(x_1-x_2)^{2}\qquad ...(3)$

Adding Equations (1),(2) and (3)

$$V(x)=V(x_1)+V(x_2)+V(x_3)$$

$$V(x) = kx^{2}_1 + kx^{2}_2 - kx_1x_2$$

Comment: For the middle spring $(x_1-x_2)^2$ in eq. 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different take on someone else's answer that does not assume the spring constants are necessarily the same.  It also uses the *inspection* method, based on the idea that the potential energy of a spring is $\frac{1}{2}\kappa \times \hbox{stretch}^2$ (or compression).

For your first spring on the left, the stretch would come from the displacement $x_1$ so $V_1=\frac{1}{2}\kappa_1 x_1^2$.  For the spring in the middle the stretch is $\vert x_1-x_2\vert $ so you'd get $V_2=\frac{1}{2}\kappa_2(x_1-x_2)^2$.  For the spring on the right $V_3=\frac{1}{2}\kappa_3 x_2^2$.

Then it's just a matter of finding the $\kappa_i$'s using the equations of motion:
\begin{align}
m\ddot{x_1}&=-\kappa_1 x_1 -\kappa_2 (x_1-x_2)=-(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)x_2+\kappa_2x_2\, ,\\
m\ddot{x_2}&=\kappa_2(x_1-x_2)-\kappa_3 x_2=-(\kappa_2+\kappa_3)x_2+\kappa_2 x_1
\end{align}

Direct comparison with your EOMs  yields $\kappa_2=\kappa_1=\kappa_3=k$ so the net potential energy is
$$
V=V_1+V_2+V_3=\frac{1}{2}k\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+(x_1-x_2)^2\right)\, .
$$