# Kinetic and Potential Energy of a multi degree of freedom (MDOF) system

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy, linear-systems

Consider the following MDOF system:

$M\ddot x+Kx=F$

where $M$ and $K$ are the mass and stiffness matrix respectively, and $x$ and $F$ are the displacement and force vectors.

How can one determine the potential and kinetic energy?

Comment: Related : [Eigenvalue equation for kinetic and potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266889/eigenvalue-equation-for-kinetic-and-potential-energy).

Comment: Related: https//physics.stackexchange.com/q/748665

Comment: Multiply with $~\dot x~$ you obtain $~\dfrac{d}{dt}\,\left( \dfrac{1}{2}M\dot x^{2}\right) =\left( F-kx\right) \dfrac{dx}{dt}~$ integrate this equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

$$\b M\,\ddot{\b{x}}+\b K\,\b x=\b F$$

multiply from the left with $~\frac{d}{dt}{\b{x}}$

$$\dot{\b{x}}\,\cdot \left(\b M\,\ddot{\b{x}}\right)+\frac{d}{dt}{\b{x}}\,\cdot\,\left(\b K\,\b x\right)=\frac{d}{dt}{\b{x}}\cdot\b F\tag 1$$

thus equation (1)

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12\dot{\b{x}}^T\b M\,\dot{\b{x}}\right)+\frac{d}{dt}{\b{x}}\,\cdot\,\left(\b K\,\b x\right)=\frac{d}{dt}{\b{x}}\cdot\b F$$

multiply with $~dt~$ and integrate (assume $~\b F~$ is constant)

$$ \underbrace{\frac 12\dot{\b{x}}^T\b M\,\dot{\b{x}}}_{\text{kinetic energy}} +
\underbrace{\frac 12\b x^T\,\b K\,\b x-\b F\cdot x}_{\text{potential energy}}=0$$

---

assume you have this scalar equation

$$ m\ddot x+k\,x=F$$

multiply with $~\dot x~$
$$\dot x\,m\,\ddot x+\dot x\,k\,x=\dot x\,F$$

with $$~\dot x\,m\,\ddot x~=\frac m2\frac {d}{dt}\,\dot x^2$$
you obtain

$$\frac m2\frac {d}{dt}\,\dot x^2+\frac{dx}{dt}\,k\,x=
\frac{dx}{dt}\,F\\
\frac m2 {d}\,(\dot x^2)+{dx}\,k\,x=
{dx}\,F\\
\int \frac m2 {d}\,(\dot x^2)+\int{dx}\,k\,x=
\int{dx}\,F\\$$

$$\frac m2 \,(\dot x^2)+\frac{k}{2}\,x^2=F\,x$$

If you deals with vectors and matrices you obtain the above result

Comment: Thank you Eli. Could you explain your steps from equation (1) to rewriting? Also, the potential energy should be divided by 2 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes you are right.  What is not clear for you ?

Comment: @Mark I put more details